# SharePoint2010 Installation using Command Shell

Tags: windows-7, sharepoint-2010, installation

Hi All
i am installing share Point 2010 on windows 7 using Command Shell how can i enter Data Base credential like user id and password of database When  runnig New-SPConfigurationDatabase comamnd thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read the documentation before posting : [New-SPConfigurationDatabase](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff607838.aspx).

There is well explained `DatabaseCredentials` argument

you may even call `help New-SPConfigurationDatabase -detailed` to find what you are looking for